# Qt5 moc not generating file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, qt5, moc

I'm making a c++ plugin for maya as a dynamic library using VS2015, until now, I had no usage of Qt5, but I now need the Q_Gadget and Q_Enum functionality from Qt5.6.1 so I started to setup my vs to include qt, everything is compiling and I have no problem to use any of  Qt class in my library, but when I try to use any of the qt's property system (Q_GADGET, Q_ENUM, etc), the moc don't seem to generate any file, I'm using the Qt VS tools 2.

I've read somewhere that I should convert my project to a Qt project, but the explanation on how to do it are very unclear, and i'm not sure if I can actually do it for my current project who have a huge amount of file.

is there a way to setup the moc to run over all my .h and to include the generated file automatically ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could fix my issues using help provided on this page :

[automatic mocing in visual studio](https://vperi.com/2012/04/23/automatic-mocing-in-visual-studio/)

We create a VS property file (.props) inside the project with custom target before ClCompile that will load all .hpp file and execute moc.exe on them

the .props modified for my 5.6.1 project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourceDir>$(ProjectDir)</SourceDir>
    <CppDir>$(SourceDir)/</CppDir>
    <GenDir>$(SourceDir)/Generated</GenDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <QtDir>D:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.6\msvc2015</QtDir>
    <MocExt>hpp</MocExt>
    <Moc>$(QtDir)/bin/moc.exe</Moc>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Inputs="@(QtIncludes)" 
          Name="Moc" 
          BeforeTargets="ClCompile" 
          Outputs="@(QtIncludes->'$(GenDir)/moc_%(Filename).cpp')">
    <Exec Command = "$(Moc) &quot;%(QtIncludes.identity)&quot; -nw -o $(GenDir)/moc_%(Filename).cpp $(MocFlags)"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CreateDirectories" BeforeTargets="Moc">
    <MakeDir
        Directories="$(GenDir)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Inputs="@(CopyToOutput)"
          Name="CopytoOut"
          Outputs="@(CopyToOutput->'%(DestinationFolder)/%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
          AfterTargets="Link">
  </Target>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <QtIncludes Include="$(ProjectDir)/**/*.$(MocExt)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```